# How to simplify this test condition on strings: if one is entered, the other must be entered too?

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, logic

I have written the following condition expression.
It works just fine...I am trying to figure out/learn a clever way to decrease the amount of code.
Perhaps using some c# Boolean logical operators in an advanced manner.

```
if ((!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyServer.ParameterValue) &&
     String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyPort.ParameterValue))
    || (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyPort.ParameterValue) &&
        String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyServer.ParameterValue)))
{
    result = "If one is present, both must be entered for Proxy Server, Proxy Port.";
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's simpler, but it scales: `string[] values = { ProxyServer.ParameterValue, ProxyPort.ParameterValue }; if (values.Any(str => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) && values.Any(str => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))`

Comment: Interesting way of handing it.  I do like the scaling aspect you provided as it provides a solution more flexible than XOR in terms of volume.

Comment: @BruceBWilson I updated my answer to add a function that accepts an indefinite number of values to produce the same expected result without using LINQ and only the XOR, as well as a generic version independent of the check condition.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Wow!  Thanks for providing a comprehensive solution.  Awesome Sauce!

Answer (score 2):

**Evaluate if one of two conditions is satisfied but not both are equal**

```
( !a && b ) || ( a && !b )
```

You can use the `^` aka the [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or): one or other but not both.

```
  if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyServer.ParameterValue) ^ string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyPort.ParameterValue) )
  {
    ...
  }
```

Thus here are the results:

```
ProxyServer    ProxyPort    IsNotProvided(ProxyServer) ^ IsNotProvided(ProxyPort)

empty          empty        false
provided       empty        true
empty          provided     true
provided       provided     false
```

[Logical exclusive OR operator (C# Language reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-)

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

**Evaluate if one of several conditions is satisfied but not all are equal**

To check more than two values, you can perhaps use the LINQ suggested by @itsme86, else this method for speed and memory performance:

```
static bool CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot(params string[] values)
{
  if ( values.Length < 2 ) return false; // or throw new Exception();
  bool firstIsNullOrWhiteSpace = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(values[0]);
  bool result = firstIsNullOrWhiteSpace ^ string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(values[1]);
  if ( values.Length > 2 )
    for ( int index = 2; index < values.Length; index++ )
      result = result || ( firstIsNullOrWhiteSpace ^ string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(values[index]) );
  return result;
}
```

*Test*

```
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "", "", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "", "", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", "", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "", "", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a", "", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "", "a", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", "", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a", "a", ""));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("", "a", "a", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "", "a", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a", "", "a"));
  Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsProvidedAndSomeOthersNot("a", "a", "a", "a"));
```

(Hope I don't forget combinations...)

*Output*

```
False
True
True
False

False
True
True
True
True
True
True
False

False
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

**Version with a generic and a delegate**

```
static bool CheckIfOneIsTrueButNotAllAreEqual<T>(Func<T, bool> check, params T[] values)
{
  if ( values.Length < 2 ) return false; // or throw new Exception();
  bool resultFirst = check(values[0]);
  bool result = resultFirst ^ check(values[1]);
  if ( values.Length > 2 )
    for ( int index = 2; index < values.Length; index++ )
      result = result || ( resultFirst ^ check(values[index]) );
  return result;
}
```

*Usage*

```
Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsTrueButNotAllAreEqual(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, "", ""));
Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsTrueButNotAllAreEqual(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, "a", ""));
Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsTrueButNotAllAreEqual(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, "", "a"));
Console.WriteLine(CheckIfOneIsTrueButNotAllAreEqual(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, "a", "a"));
```